# How to prepare array of dispatching actions and they execute them with Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, redux-thunk

I have an array of IDs. E.g. `[1, 2, 3]` and I redux-thunk `callBackend` which takes an ID and calls the backend.

I could loop through the list and `dispatch(callBackend(arrayItem))` sequentially for every item in the array. However, I would like to prepare an array of promises

`const promises = [dispatch(callBackend(i), dispatch(callBackend(i+1), .., dispatch(callBackend(n))]`

And then execute `const results = await Promise.all(promises);`

I cannot figure it out how to prepare the array of promises.

Comment: `promises = arr.map(x => callBackend(x))` or `arr.map(callBackend)`?

Comment: The problem is that the callBackend starts being executed within the map function. I would like that Promises.all() starts with callBackend functions executions

Comment: I think you need this: 
https://react-redux.js.org/api/batch

Comment: Hi @JivkoJelev thanks. Its close to it. The challenge is how to prepare n number of dispatches